# Migrate Guid Primary key and Clustered Index to INT (Azure SQL)

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, azure, primary-key, clustered-index

**Context**

We started out developing a system that uses GUID as PK that were marked as clustered by default with Entity Framework (I know...). I now realize how this might be affecting performance when inserting in the database especially since the GUID is used as clustered index.

I did some research and found a lot of useful information but I'm still confused on how I should go about resolving this. Furthermore, we have a production database with almost a million rows that have to be migrated if we decide to go from GUID PK to INT.

**Question(s):**

1. An alternate solution is to change the clustered index to be another column (ie: DateTime) but how much of a difference in performance will this bring us if our joins use primarily the PK?
2. Start using sequential guids (NHibernate Comb), but again if our existing Guids were not sequential, will it have an impact if we just start using sequential guid for new rows?
3. If the optimal solution is to migrate from GUID to INT then would it be possible to do it with Entity Code-First Migrations (if possible at all)?
4. Should I even worry about this at this point? Maybe it's pre-optimization but the database is growing quickly and I don't want to be down the road after 2-3 million rows and realize that we have to fix it asap.

**Constraints**

- MSSQL (hosted on Azure SQL)
- Entity Framework Code-First Migrations (preferably)
- Existing database that needs to be migrated

I appreciate any constructive feedback that could help me take the right decision. I'm not looking for a written out solution but maybe just some guidance that will point me to the right path.

Comment: Hi Ryan, what did you end up doing? I'm currently facing the same issue and I'm considering adding a new column (int, identity), set it as clustered index and leave my PK (Guid) as non-clustered

Answer (score 2):

Having GUID as PK is not a problem. But it can result in performance issues when you have a CLUSTERED index on GUID column. So you can keep all your PKs as they are and at the same time migrate CLUSTERED indexes to whatever you want.

There will still exist an index on every PK column (guid), so join performance on unique values will be the same. Changes will affect only write and probably read performance. There will be less page splits on writes because rows will be appended to the end of index sequentially instead of inserting into random pages in the middle and in the beginning of the clustered index.

You can alter your PK with option NONCLUSTERED and create another clustered index (which does not have to be PK or even unique).